# Modifying the default dialog shown on file upload error in MS CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

We have requirement like 
Sum of all the attachments file sizes should not exceed the Max upload file size configured in System Settings in MS CRM 2013.
OOB the Max upload file size is valid for a single file.

We have implement the logic by reading the organiztion setting and validate the file sizes
when the sum of all the attachments of an activity exceeds this size we are throwing invalidpluginexecution exception.

[image]
Which is showing the entire error message in the window.

Our requirement is to show only the custom message as Highlighted.

Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to prevent the stacktrace from being displayed in this dialog. Microsoft clearly did not implement a graceful Business Process error handling here.